# Github API v3, post issues / authentication

Tags: api, authentication, github, axios, github-api-v3

I am working on a project making a Kanban board using the Github API v3.
I have no problem with get methods, but when it comes to post methods i get a 404 response, and from what i read in the documentation, this seems to be a authentication error.

I am using personal token for authentication, and have successfully posted through postman, but when i try to post through my own application i get the error.

Link to project if anyone's interested : https://github.com/ericyounger/Kanban-Electron

Below is the code used for posting to github.

Might there be a problem with my code below? Or might it be settings in relation with the token?

```
postIssue(json){

        let packed = this.packPost(json);
        return Axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.user}/${this.repo}/issues`, packed);
    }

    packPost(json) {
        return {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `token ${this.tokenAuth}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({title: json.title})
        };
    }
```

This is what i receive:

```
{message: "Not Found", documentation_url: "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue"}
message: "Not Found"
documentation_url: "https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue"
```

[Console log error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLssl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick :)

```
    postIssue(json){
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3.raw',
            "Authorization": `token ${this.tokenAuth}`,
        };

        return Axios.post(`https://api.github.com/repos/${this.user}/${this.repo}/issues`, json , {headers: headers});
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any detailed logs, my first attempt would be to set `body` to not send the string representation of the body

```
body: {title: json.title}
```

Comment: Useful tip! :-)  But unfortunately, it didn't solve it. I added some more error logs if that helps.